# Error with JQUERY in Multimedia Library of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

[image]
With the latest version of Wordpress I can't upload media. It shows this message from debugger:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=] load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,jquery-ui-core&ver=4.2.2:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=]
```

[image: It doesn't show any item and when I try to upload a photo, it keeps the same screen]

It seems to be a jQuery problem, I tried to re-upload again files from wp-includes and upload.php, but it didn't work.

It is important not to downgrade for our project, how can I solve that?

UPDATE: Key error to solve (not the a[rel=] one)
[image]

UPDATE 2: It still fails at uploading, but it only has now the a[rel=] error
[image]

Comment: @davidkonrad I have tested and the second error that is shown is the one that only happens in the upload screen, not the a[rel=]:    load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,underscore,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-b…:541 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line into your `wp-config.php`, preferably after

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
```

so it becomes

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
define ('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Comment: What's the new error? Have you tried clearing cache and try again?

Comment: Its the load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,underscore,shortcode,ba‌​ckbone,wp-util,wp-b…:541 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined I have posted details in UPDATE at description of question

Comment: If the `load-scripts.php` still being called, then either you haven't clear your cache, or the `CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` haven't been in the right place. The purpose of `CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` is to disable `load-scripts.php`

Comment: @tuanahh I cleaned caché and It solved the hasClass error, but It keeps failing with the photo upload and keeps showing the a[rel=] error. I attach new screenshot at description.

Comment: Now shows this error: Uncaught TypeError: handlers.min.js?ver=4.2.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: plupload.predictRuntime is not a function

Comment: Now it seems like a plugin specific problem. Try to identify that plugin and disable it maybe?

Comment: I have just disabled all plugins and the same error happens @tuananh